# Is being a Cauchy sequence equivalent to $ \lim_{n\to+\infty}d(x_{n+k},x_n)=0$ for every $k$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

Is this statement true?

> In a metric spase $(E,d)$, a sequence $(x_n)$ is Cauchy if and only if $  \forall k\in \mathbb{N}, \lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}d(x_{n+k},x_n)=0$

I proved that $\Rightarrow$ is true,indeed if $(x_n)$ is Cauchy then for all $\varepsilon>0,\exists n_0\in\mathbb{N}, \forall p,q\geq n, d(x_p,x_q)<\varepsilon$ it still right for all $ n\geq n_0$ and $m=n+k>n\geq n_0$

But I don't know if $\Leftarrow$ is true ?

Comment: Please show your proof for the $\implies$ direction.  I don't think the implication holds, so I'd like to see if your proof is logically sound.  Here is a counter example: Suppose $E = \mathbb{R}$ and $d(a,b) = |a - b|$.  Let $(x_{n}) = (\frac{1}{n})$.  This sequence is Cauchy but for each $n$, $d(x_{n + k}, x_{n}) > 0$ for all $k$.

Comment: Maybe $...\to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ instead of $...=0$

Comment: Your condition states that all the terms are equal. This certainly implies that the sequence is Cauchy, but certainly there are Cauchy sequences whose terms are not all equal. In other words $(\Rightarrow)$ is false.

Comment: @GPerez why down vote ? i don't understand your answer

Comment: @Vrouvrou That's not my downvote. I'll write an answer to explain better.

Comment: @GPerez i edited my question

Comment: Ah, never mind then (the way you had it, every term was at distance zero from all the others i.e. they're all the same).

Comment: What is written in the question: "$(x_n)$ is Cauchy $\Longleftrightarrow \forall k\in \mathbb{N}, \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow+\infty}d(x_{n+k},x_n)=0$" is wrong, as the example of $x_n=\log n$ for every $n$ shows (for the Euclidean metrics).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equivalence is not correct.

To see this, consider any divergent series of real numbers $\sum a_n$ such that 
$a_n\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$; for example $a_n=\frac1n$. Then define $x_n=a_1+\dots +a_n$. This is a non-Cauchy sequence (as any non-convergent sequence of real numbers), but $x_{n+k}-x_n=a_{n+1}+\dots +a_{n+k}\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ for any fixed $k\in\mathbb N$, since this is the sum of $k$ terms tending to $0$; that is, $d(x_n,x_{n+k})\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. So the implication $\Leftarrow$ does not hold.

If you prefer, you can take $x_n=\log n$ or $x_n=\sqrt{n}$, and check that $x_{n+k}-x_n\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$, for any $k\in\mathbb N$.

On the other hand, your proof of the other implication is correct.

Last remark : in fact the assumption "$\forall k\in\mathbb N\; d(x_{n+k},x_n)\to 0$" is equivalent to the seemingly weaker "$d(x_{n+1},x_n)\to 0$", as you can easily check.

Comment: why $\sqrt{n+k}-\sqrt{n} \rightarrow 0$ ?

Comment: For example, because it is equal to $\frac{k}{\sqrt{n+k}+\sqrt{n}}\cdot$

Comment: Ok that's right and why is not a Cauchy sequence

Comment: Please can you tel me if  $\forall \varepsilon>0, \exists n_0\in \mathbb{N}, \forall (n,k)\in\mathbb{N}^2,(n\geq n_0\Rightarrow d(x_n,x_{n+k})\leq \varepsilon)$ is the same as $\forall k\in \mathbb{N}, \lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}d(x_{n+k},x_n)=0$ please i nee your help

Comment: No, this is not the same : the first property says "$(x_n)$ is Cauchy".

Comment: but how to see the différence, it is like the definition of lim ?

Comment: No. If you write down the second property with quantifiers, there is a $\forall k$ coming before the $\exists n_0$; which makes all the difference because in this way $n_0$ is allowed to depend on $k$, whereas it must be independent of $k$ in the first property.

Comment: ok thank you, but please are you sure that my proof for the author sense is correct ? thank you

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

of course that it's wrong !!
Consider $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$, the sequence converge therefore it's a Cauchy sequence, but $d(x_{n+k},x_n)\neq 0$ for all $k$.

The correct statement  would be

$(x_n)$ is cauchy $\iff \forall \varepsilon>0, \exists N\in\mathbb N:\forall n,k\in\mathbb N, n\geq N\implies d(x_{n+k},x_n)<\varepsilon$

and this is the definition of a Cauchy sequence as well !

Comment: what is the difference between $\forall k\in\mathbb{N}, \lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}d(x_{n+k},x_n)=0$ and your statement ? please

Comment: I don't see why $\lim_{n\to\infty}d(x_{n+k},x_n)\ne0$.

Comment: @user84413 : you cannot see it, since this is a wrong answer.

Answer (score -5):

With the way you edited it, you actually just wrote the definition of a cauchy sequence in a different manner.

$\lim_{n\to+\infty}d(x_{n+k},x_n)=0$ means that for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $N$ such that $d(x_{n+k},x_n)<\varepsilon\ \forall\ n>N$.

But since $k$ can be any arbitrary natural number, this means that $d(x_n,x_m)<\varepsilon\ \forall\ n>N,m>N$.

Thus, you didn't really change anything there.

Comment: so this equivalence is true right ?

Comment: It is true, but it isn't really any different from the definition itself.

Comment: One told me that it isn't true and we see this with the hrmonic series

Comment: That was BEFORE you put the limit there. Without the limit, that guy is right, it's wrong. But when you put the limit as $n\to\infty$ there, the equivalence is established.

Comment: why down vote ?

Comment: That wasn't my down vote.

Comment: "With the way you edited it, you actually just wrote the definition of a cauchy sequence in a different manner." Not at all.

Comment: How is it not so? Was there anything wrong in my reasoning?

Comment: i don't understand it is right or not i don't fnd an example of a sequence where $d(x_{n+k},x_n)\rightarrow 0$ but $(x_n)$ is not a cauchy sequence

Comment: @HasanSaad Write down carefully the statements "for all $k$ $(d(x_n,x_{n+k})\to 0$" and "$(x_n)$ is Cauchy" with quantifiers. You'll see that the order of the quantifiers is not exactly the same.

Comment: Oh, now I got what I did wrong. Thanks for clarification.